# what is object in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to learn javascript object, i spend time on the internet and learn about the javascript object a bit and i am confused what is use of object and how to build your own object in javascript. i also see some javascript function in which they use their own custom object. i have some code for example.

```
var animationSections = {   
        'intro': 0,
        'over': 200,
        'around': 1600,
        'through': 3500,
        'share': 5000
    };
```

i copy above given code from one javascript file it is for animation and they use this object.

```
startAt: 0+animationSections.over
```

now my question will come up why we use animationSections.over rather we can use '200'

Comment: i am new to javascript as you can see i asked lot of question here and i get the response to this website is like teacher for me and sorry about the my english i am not good with my english.

Comment: you might want to take a look on what [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is. JavaScript is a [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), object oriented language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to have some object oriented programming background.So you can understand much more better here.An OBJECT has a property.In this animationsector is an Object.Instead of saying 200 directly, represent it via Object.property mechanism.This will make your code much more cleaner and easy to maintain.Also, after sometime, when you revisit the code after sometime, it will be bit difficult to remember or map why 200 is used.But instead, if maintain an object and say 'over', then you can be able to identify its significance.it represents the context.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

What objects are is a very big question.  The use of objects are expressed in detail as chapters in books.

---

To answer your question, you could use `200`, instead of `animationSections.over`.

The primary use of objects in your example is a better way to write more descriptive/organized code.  Though, as stated above, there are many other benefits to objects (e.g. looping through properties, localizing variables, passing as parameters, etc).

The concept of an object is a collection of variables as key/value pairs, where values can be static or even functions references.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link will answer your questions about why you should use an object: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, everything that is not a primitive value is an Object. That means a structure that can have properties, and has (can have) a prototype object it inherits from. How to build and use them would go beyond the scope of this answer ([short introduction](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)).

---

> Why dont we use the value `200` here?

We could, but if we needed it somewhere else we needed to repeat it. As it is a configuration option, we might need to change it in a lot of places, so we use variables in here

> Why dont we use [a set of] variables here?

We could, but the use of objects has some advantages:

- It structures the data, in here the options. Similiar structures will result in similiar options. Especially useful for settings, you can see which options belong together, in here: to the animation
- We can use more than one similiar object (objects with the same keys). We could not use the same variable name for different variables.
- We could loop over it (not needed in this example)

Comment: Even a function is an Object  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: Did I stated otherwise or do you just miss the explicit indication?